# Subtotal of child records without COUNT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

ParentSub Table:

| ParentCode | SubCode | CompanyName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MEGA1 | MEGA1 | Megacorp |
| MEGA1 | SUBC1 | Subsidiary Company |
| MEGA1 | EASC1 | East Coast Operations |
| MEGA1 | EURC1 | Europe Company |
| BIGLY | ALPH1 | Alphabet Company |
| BIGLY | BIGLY | Big Development |
| HOTS1 | HOTS1 | Hot Dog Company |

I want:

| Parent | Subsidiary | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MEGA1 | MEGA1 | Megacorp |
| MEGA1 | SUBC1 | Subsidiary Company |
| MEGA1 | EASC1 | East Coast Operations |
| MEGA1 | EURC1 | Europe Company |
| MEGA1 | NULL | 4 |
| BIGLY | ALPH1 | Alphabet Company |
| BIGLY | BIGLY | Big Development |
| BIGLY | NULL | 2 |

Surely there is a way to make ROLLUP do this?

```
SELECT ParentCode, SubCode, CompanyName
FROM ParentSub
GROUP BY ParentCode WITH ROLLUP
```

I don't want the COUNTs in the rows and I don't want them in Aggregate functions until the group changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`GROUPING SETS` might be better than `ROLLUP` here, as you only want 2 levels of rollup and you miss out other levels.**

We can also use `GROUPING()` to check if a column has been aggregated. Note that `COUNT` needs to be converted to `varchar` to hold it in the same column

```sql
SELECT
    ParentCode,
    SubCode,
    CASE WHEN GROUPING(CompanyName) = 1
      THEN CAST(COUNT(*) AS varchar(10))
      ELSE CompanyName END
     AS CompanyName
FROM ParentSub
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (ParentCode, SubCode, CompanyName),
    (ParentCode)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you could do this with ROLLUP, but this is how I would do it:

```
WITH OrderRows AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ParentCode ORDER BY SubCode, CompanyName) AS ORD, * FROM @ParentSub
),
AddCountRows AS (
    SELECT ORD, ParentCode, SubCode, CompanyName FROM OrderRows 
    UNION
    -- child counts
    SELECT 
        -- find where to insert this row in the ordered rows above
        (SELECT MAX(ORD) + 1 FROM OrderRows WHERE ParentCode = p.ParentCode) AS ORD, 
        ParentCode, 
        NULL, 
        CAST(COUNT(*) AS varchar(10)) AS CNT 
    FROM @ParentSub p GROUP BY ParentCode
)
-- obtain the data we want and order by the parent and the row order we calculated
SELECT ParentCode AS Parent, SubCode AS Subsidiary, CompanyName AS Name FROM AddCountRows ORDER BY ParentCode, ORD
```